# Is $\ L = \{ \ w \in \{a, b, c\}^* \ | \ w = uv \ \ and \ \ \#_a(u) + \#_b(u) = \#_b(v) + \#_c(v) \ \} $ regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I wonder whether the following language is regular:  $$ L = \{ \ w \in \{a, b, c\}^* \ | \ w = uv \ \ and \ \ \#_a(u) + \#_b(u) = \#_b(v) + \#_c(v) \  \} $$ where $\ \#_x(w) $ is the number of occurrences of$\ x $ in$\ w $.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? If you "don't know where to start", review your course material and/or peruse [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843).

Answer (score 3):

Your language is not regular, since
$$
L \cap a^*bc^* = \{ a^n b c^m : n \neq m \}.
$$
I'll let you figure out why.